# type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'Route<Object?>' in type cast

Tags: flutter, dart

I got the problem when I try to navigation page. I want to user Navigation from cart page to home page and cannot back to cart page. But I got the error like this:

```
type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'Route<Object?>' in type cast
```

I have try a lot to fix the code, but it didn't work.

**The code:**

```dart
TextButton(
    onPressed: () {
        Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(context, '/home', (route) => false);
    },)
```

How to fix it?

Comment: Could you show your **RouteFactory = Route? Function(
RouteSettings settings
)** function code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The defination of [`pushAndRemoveUntil`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Navigator/pushAndRemoveUntil.html) is:

```
Future<T?> pushAndRemoveUntil<T extends Object?>(
   BuildContext context,
   Route<T> newRoute,
   RoutePredicate predicate
)
```

Use the following updated code:

```
Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
  context,
  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomePage()),
  (route) => false,
);
```

Comment: Hi @leo, I am glad it worked, please consider upvoting the post aswell if it solved your problem, It helps further for the people having same issue. Thank you